# How to disable RubyMine code completion after comment line ending in period?

Tags: rubymine, code-completion

I am using RubyMine 6.3.2.  When I type the following line and press return/enter:

```
  # This is a comment.
```

the editor inserts additional text, resulting in:

```
  # This is a comment.after() do

end
```

I understand that this happens because "aft" is the first item on the dropdown that appears after typing ".".  I can preventing the insertion by pressing space after return/enter, but that adds a space to the end of the line, and I have to remember to do it.

Is there a way to disable code completion within comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15127
It was fixed in 6.3.3, which was released yesterday: http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2014/06/rubymine-6-3-3-rspec-3-code-insight-other-fixes/

This duplicate bug report http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15195 gives a workaround, which is to go to RubyMine's registry (Control-Shift-A and type "registry") and uncheck "show.live.templates.in.completion". That works, and it revealed to me the existence of RubyMine's registry, so that's cool.