# Rubymine 7.0: Disable automatic insertion of "end"

Tags: ide, rubymine-7

I would like to disable automatic insertion of `end` for `def`/`while`/`class`/etc. in Rubymine 7.0.

For example, if I type `def` and press enter, an `end` is automatically added below the new line:

```
# Before I press enter:
def|

# After I press enter:
def
  |
end
```

I've looked through the options in **File > Settings...** and can see options for similar features (such as automatic insertion of closing `)` characters, which I have unchecked) but nothing specifically for `end`.

An answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318226/how-to-disable-rubymine-code-completion-after-comment-line-ending-in-period) suggests using the Rubymine "registry" (accessible via **Help > Find Action... > "registry"** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829639/4200092)) but this doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the line **End (on blank line)** in **File > Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately, I'm not using Rubymine any more (I've switched my work machine over from Windows 8 to Debian) so won't be able to confirm that this works right away. I'll ask someone else at the office if they can verify this for me, and accept/upvote your answer once I'm sure that it does what I want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why haven't you stuck with RubyMine? It's working alright on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: The machine I use was already set up with Windows 8 and Rubymine when I started working here; I didn't actually *want* to use either of them!