# RubyMine - automatically detect .each, .map, and other iterator types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

In RubyMine I can write

```
# @param [Array<MyClass>] things
def foo(things)
end
```

and RubyMine will autocomplete MyClass methods for `things.first.*`. However, when I loop through each, like:

```
# @param [Array<MyClass>] things
def foo(things)
    things.each { |t| t.* }
end
```

RubyMine loses its type inference. I know I can add comments to specify block parameter types, but looping through an object of some type should only yield parameters of that type anyway.

**Is there any way I can write a custom rule for RubyMine so that `.each`, `.map`, and other iterators are presumed to have the type of the variable its called upon?**

Comment: Contact support i 've meet them personaly they are REALY quick to respond .

Comment: this might be useful.!
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318226/how-to-disable-rubymine-code-completion-after-comment-line-ending-in-period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318226/how-to-disable-rubymine-code-completion-after-comment-line-ending-in-period)

Comment: there's now an issue on jetbrains for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18531

Answer (score 1):

From my research, it looks like you may be able to annotate like so:

```
# @param [Array<MyClass>] things
def foo(things)
  things.each {
    # @type [MyClass] t 
    |t|
    t.*
  }
end
```

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9142#comment=27-787975

Comment: yeah you can explicitly annotate block params, but the point of my question was that I don't want to have to do that for every enumeration. it should be implicit